# jQuery two different selectors but defining $(this) depending on which one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code I just wrote which originally I did as two separate ones but want to clean up and have within one method:

```
$('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-first-name input,#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-last-name input').blur(function() {
    var firstname = $(this).val();
    var lastname = $(this).val();
    $.ceAjax('request', fn_url('ac.email'), {
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            'firstname': firstname,
            'lastname': lastname
        },
        caching: true
    });
});
```

I'm rather new to JS / jQuery. As you can see I have this set twice for both firstname and lastname which of course I know won't work. Anyway of getting this for what I need or rather requesting in the line above?

Am I right in thinking maybe this would work?

```
var firstname_sel = '#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-first-name input';
var lastname_sel = '#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-last-name input';
$(firstname_sel,lastname_sel).blur(function() {
    var firstname = $(firstname_sel).val();
    var lastname = $(lastname_sel).val();
    $.ceAjax('request', fn_url('ac.email'), {
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            'firstname': firstname,
            'lastname': lastname
        },
        caching: true
    });
});
```

I've not tested but want to check first if it's the right way of doing it.

Comment: You might like to rephrase your question, as at the moment, it could be flagged as 'primarily opinion based' and there's no real way to answer "Am I right in thinking this would work" other than yes/no

Comment: Thats good that i explained it clearly lol currently it is not working, and ive just changed selector to the following but getting error so not sure: var firstname_sel = 'onestepcheckout .ty-billing-first-name input';
 var lastname_sel = 'onestepcheckout .ty-billing-last-name input';
 $("#"+firstname_sel",#"+lastname_sel).blur(function() {

Comment: which returns: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that would work. There are some things you could change to make it more efficient or friendly.

First, make sure you want to execute that ajax call on `blur` (remember, it is going to get called every time the user exits the two inputs). An alternative would be to wrap your inputs in a `<form>` and bind to the `submit` event of that form which would submit when the user clicks a `<button type="submit" />`.

Second, you might want some validation since one field might be empty as the user exits the other input: `firstname = firstname === '' ? 'Default' : firstname;` or something similar.

And finally, there are a lot of ways to handle your binding/selection question. You might do this instead:

```
<input id="first-name" class="name-input" ... />
<input id="last-name" class="name-input" ... />

$('.name-input').bind('blur', function() {
  var fName = $('#first-name').val();
  var lName = $('#last-name').val();

  ... validation code from above then ajax call ...
});
```

But some folks might not condone associating functionality with class since that could easily be missed by new developers looking at the code or accidentally copied and/or mistaken for a style class.

The only thing you could almost certainly change above is to make your selector more simple by adding an id to the input itself instead of selecting based on the parent elements.

Comment: That would be a solution, however i cannot modify the template as core files so would break if updated but it is a solution so will mark valid. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok managed to work it out, here was the solution

```
var firstname_sel = '#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-first-name input';
var lastname_sel = '#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-last-name input';
$(firstname_sel+','+lastname_sel).blur(function() {
    var firstname = $(firstname_sel).val();
    var lastname = $(lastname_sel).val();
    $.ceAjax('request', fn_url('ac.email'), {
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            'firstname': firstname,
            'lastname': lastname
        },
        caching: true
    });
});
```